# Custom ordering Shield UI the bars in a bar type chart

Tags: jquery, bar-chart, shieldui

I am using the ShieldUI charting component and am looking for a way to render bars one over the other, preferably with different width in order to avoid visibility issues. 
They are usually rendered side by side and I cannot find a way to re-position them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been implemented in the newest release of the control. It is demonstrated in the following example:

https://demos.shieldui.com/web/bar-chart/overlapped-bar

You need to set the divideSeries property to false.